# Albums containing pictures from wall/timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall, image

In my app I need to get all users FB content (status updates, pictures, videos).
When getting the wall/timeline posts I make the following requests:

> 1. Feed: http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
> 2. Posts: http://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token=...
> 3. Statuses: http://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=...

- and I get all 3 types of elements (status updates, pictures, videos) for the current user.

When getting the photos I first make an albums request:

> http://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...

then for each album I get the photos inside.

Some of the album (like "Wall Photos" or "Mobile Photos") contain pictures that I already have, after making the wall/timeline requests, so I don't need them again. I want to skip those albums and so far I've been using a simple condition (in PHP):

```
if ( !in_array($album->type, array('wall','mobile')) ) { ... }
```

But now I saw that there might be other albums that contain photos already shown on the wall/timeline - in this case "Instagram Pics". The problem is that this album has the type = normal just like the albums that user creates manually (and these are the album that I need to process). Of course I can add a condition like:

```
... && ($album->name != 'Instagram Pics')
```

but if the name of the album changes this will no longer be a valid condition, and I would like to avoid it. Plus I realize that there might be other types of albums that contain pictures shown on the wall and that would generate the same problem again.

Another problem with this is that the two items (picture saved in album and picture posted on wall) have different ids so I can not identify the doubles this way.

My question is: How can I identify the albums that contain pictures that are also shown on the  wall/timeline (= will be present when requesting the wall posts) so that I can skip them when processing users personal albums? 
Thank you.

Comment: loana, /me/feed returns all types of posts, there would be no need in making a request for me statuses, unless your using for separate function.

Comment: Thank you for that note, that will be a good improvement in my code :)